# How to read incoming excel file in base64 and extract their data in C# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, base64, epplus

I am making an API using C# that takes excel files and transforms and saves its data to database.
I am transforming the excel sheet to base64 and then convert it using epplus to excel sheet.
Problem:
I want to access the sheet without having to save the file.
My Code so far:

```
public List<ApplicantEngExamBO> receiveAndSaveApplicantData(string database64, int exam_ID)
        {
            //converting file to byte[]
            byte[] byteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(database64);
            using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(byteArray,0,byteArray.Length))
            {

                ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(memStream);
                package.Load(memStream);

                //Just testing if it got any correct data
                //It is not working
                byte[] data = package.GetAsByteArray("ID");
                var res = new List<ApplicantEngExamBO>();

                foreach (var d in data)
                {
                    res.Add(new ApplicantEngExamBO { studID = (int)d });
                }

                //return package;
                return res;
            }
        }
```

How can we read the contents of the sheet without saving it, what to do next to get the data ? Other columns include "email".

Comment: This all depends on how `Load` and the constructor works. But it looks like you're loading it twice. First time in the constructor and the second with a call to `Load`. If `Load` does not reset the stream to the beginning before it starts it is likely do just give you an empty `package`. Try resetting the stream or don't load twice.

Comment: Apparently it is just a redundant piece of code, all cases get me to the same results.

Comment: What does "Not working" mean?  Exceptions? Can you confirm that `package` has content?  Does `package.Workbook` has anything in it?

Comment: It is getting  an uninterpreted 2D byte array, so instead of getting the columns' content, I just get numbers.